# Mostrar errores en el navegador

Tags: php

Buen dia gente, alguien podría decirme como hacer para ver en mi navegador los errores de programacion de PHP?
Veo tutoriales y todos los que veo se les muestra en pantalla del navegador la linea en PHP donde se encuentra el error.
A mi me sale Error 500 y nada mas y tengo que estar mirando linea a linea donde está el error.
Uso AppServ

Answer (score 0):

El paso mas sencillo sería:

- Ingresar a la ruta de tu instalación de PHP, que pudiera estar en /appserv/php/

Y dentro de ella buscar un archivo que se llama **php.ini**, el cual contiene parámetros de configuración.

Para este caso la línea que nos interesa es:

```
display_errors = Off
```

Originalmente se encuentra deshabilitada por lo que con cambiar su valor a on debería alcanzar quedando así:

```
display_errors = on
```

Reinicias tu servidor y listo.

Sin embargo esto supone una regla de configuración general, es decir que el servidor en todo momento y a todas las peticiones les estaría imprimiendo dichos mensajes de:

- Errores fatales
- Amenazas
- Etc.

Dado eso puedes optar por una segunda opción donde solo se habilitará el mostrar mensajes de error pero de forma *local* y no para todo tu entorno, dicho lo anterior en el .php donde te cuentres trabajando puedes agregar estas líneas:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Que hará que cualquier error generado sea visible

Si tienes mas dudas y quieres consultar todos los argumentos que se le pueden pasar a dicha función; entonces te sugiero leer la [doc. de PHP en este apartado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)